# 3 django model filterset with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have 3 different django models and I want to filter using `django-filter`.
The *ORM* query I wrote below works without any problems, but how can I do this with `django-filter` (`filters.FilterSet`)?

```py
Employee.objects.filter(companyrecord__company__cname__icontains="ompanyname")
```

> THIS WORKS

it is work for me in ORM. But how can I do this in filter set. I wrote above what I want to do

**My Models:**

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(...)

class CompanyRecord(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Company(models.Model):
    cname = models.CharField(...)
```

**My FilterSet:**

```py
class EmployeeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    full_name = filters.CharFilter(field_name="full_name", lookup_expr='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
            fields = ['full_name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`field_name=…`** parameter <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#field-name) can accept a chain of field names, like when you filter. Indeed:

> Field names can traverse relationships by joining the related parts with the ORM lookup separator (`__`). e.g., a product’s `manufacturer__name`.

So you can work with:

```
class EmployeeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    full_name = filters.CharFilter(
        field_name="full_name", lookup_expr='icontains'
    )
    company_name = filters.CharFilter(
        field_name="companyrecord__company__cname", lookup_expr='icontains'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['full_name']
```

Then you thus filter with the `company_name` for that filter.